# How to import a CSV file into Quip?

Tags: quip

I need to import a CSV file into a quip worksheet.

- Is there an option to do that?

  - If yes, where is it?
- Can it be done on just worksheets or docs too?

Answer (score 0):

On quip spreadsheets, the option is `Spreadsheet` > `New` > `Upload or Import...`

[image]

For docs it is inside `Document` menu instead of `Spreadsheet`

---

Do note that Quip is not very intelligent about different types of separator characters in CSV, so you might have to edit your file before importing